# How to open a google spreadsheet by script in a browser tab

Tags: google-apps-script

I have set of spreadsheets which need to be opened in individual tabs in browser. Each sheet has got script to run on onopen trigger. Is there a way to open each spreadsheet in individual browser tabs from another mastersheet script?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't have the ability to open links from a Spreadsheet's script, the user must click the link.

You can converge all sheets into one with scripts or importRange tough.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You mean, the only option is to click the file icon in the drive folder to open a document in browser., right?

Comment: tou can also make a script that lists all anchors on a page/sidebar for the user to click. Slightly more convenient than opening from drive.

Comment: As Zig said, that's what I meant for "click the link", you make a page that shows in modelessDialog/showSideBar that has the links.